# Logging REST/SOAP services using HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring, logging

I am trying to implement `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to be able to capture the request/response as a pre/post processor. For some reason the call doesn't go through my interceptor. There are multiple examples out but I couldn't find the issue in my case. Right now I want to capture the request before it goes to actual service and log some data.

**NOTE**: I don't have any view to render.

Interceptor class:

```
public class ESignLoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  private static final String CLASS_NAME = ESignLoggingInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  @Override
  public boolean preHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler ) throws Exception {
      String url = null;
      if( request != null ) {
          url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
      }
      return true;
  }
```

}

spring.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/rest"/>
        <bean class="com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.common.logging.ESignLoggingInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/soap"/>
        <bean class="com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.common.logging.ESignLoggingInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 approaches for solving this problem, that I also faced.

**The first** is like you are trying. Please check:

1. Change

`<mvc:mapping path="/soap"/>` to `<mvc:mapping path="/soap/**"/>` 

`<mvc:mapping path="/rest"/>` to `<mvc:mapping path="/rest/**"/>`

2. Also check if you have al schemas declared. If you actually don't have it declared you should be receiving error.

`xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd"`

**The second**

1. Declare your interceptor as below

   `@Bean
    public MappedInterceptor myInterceptor() {
       return new MappedInterceptor(null, new MyLoggingInterceptor());
    }`

EDIT: Add @Component to your class